# Passing an JSON array to MVC Web API via GET

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api

I know there are tons of answers for this topic, but couldn't find the solution to my issue.
I have an ASP.NET MVC Web API that looks like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IList<Country> GetCountryList(List<long> idList)
```

And I've tried calling it like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({idList: listOfIds}),            
        type: "GET",
        url: "api/v1/util/CountryList",
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
```

The URL then looks like this:

```
https://localhost/supertext/api/v1/util/CountryList?{%22idList%22:[46,14,62,83,120]}
```

Alternative:

```
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            idList: JSON.stringify(listOfIds),
        }          
        type: "GET",
        url: "api/v1/util/CountryList",
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
```

URL:

```
https://localhost/supertext/api/v1/util/CountryList?idList=%5B46%2C14%2C62%2C83%2C120%5D
```

Both methods don't work.

Do I really have to send and receive it as a string or use POST?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

No, don't try to be sending JSON in a GET request. Use JSON with other verbs which have body, such as POST and PUT.

Do it the standard way, by decorating your action parameter with the `[FromUri]` attribute:

```
public IList<Country> GetCountryList([FromUri] List<long> idList)
{
    ...
}
```

and then just trigger the AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api/v1/util/CountryList',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { idList: [1, 2, 3] },
    traditional: true,
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
});
```

Further recommended reading for you about how the model binding in the Web API works:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-1

Comment: Thanks! This works if I hardcode data: { idList: [1, 2, 3] }, but not if I use data: JSON.stringify({idList: listOfIds}),

Comment: But why are you stringifying???? Don't `JSON.stringify` anything! I already told you not to use JSON with a GET request in my answer. Your request should look like this: `data: { idList: listOfIds }`. Obviously I assume that `listOfIds` is a javascript array of numbers.

Comment: Sorry, took a little longer to understand all of it. Working now! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**Following are two parameter Enum and objSearch **

var Enum = "ABCD";

```
var objSearch = [
              {"Name":"Navjot Angra","Age":23},
              {"Name":"Nav","Age":22}];
```

**//this is ajax method**

$.ajax({

```
   type: "GET",
   var GatwayUrl ='http//2937/' (//Your url)
   url: GatwayUrl + 'api/Certificate/GetDetail/?Enum=' + Enum +'+&objSearch='+ JSON.stringify(objSearch),
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (result) {
     if (result) {
        alert("Your Code");    
        }       }
});
```

**//this part is web api part**

[HttpGet]

public IHttpActionResult Fetch([FromUri]string Enum, [FromUri]string objSearch)
{

IHttpActionResult action=null;
return action;

}