# Passing array of integers to webapi Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, parameter-passing, model-binding

I am trying to pass an array of int but I can not get the value in the webapi method

```
var postData = { "deletedIds": deletedIds };

    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        traditional: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        cache: false,
        url: "/api/Management/Models",
        data: JSON.stringify(postData),
        success: ModelDeleted,
        error: ModelNotDeleted
    });
```

and in apiController :

```
[HttpDelete]
        public bool DeleteModel(int[] deletedIds)
        {
            return modelsRepository.DeleteModels(deletedIds);
        }
```

Comment: I tried to remove JSON.stringify but still not working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code looking pretty Ok to me. Please define structure of "deletedIds" object.
one suggestion is to Use
    new Array() 
object to initialize deletedIds property and remove JSON.stringify() .
A similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309115/how-can-i-post-an-array-of-string-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-without-a-form).

**EDIT**

Web API supports parsing content data in a variety of ways, but it does not deal with multiple posted content values. A solution for your problem could be to create a ViewModel with a property of int[] type.
Like code below,

```
public class SimpleViewModel
{
    public int[] deletedIds{ get; set; }
}

//Controller
[HttpDelete]
    public bool DeleteModel(SimpleViewModel deletedIds)
    {
        return modelsRepository.DeleteModels(deletedIds.deletedIds);
    }
```

and use it as parameter type.

Comment: I tried to use new Array but still get null on webapi method parameter

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the question you referenced is not the same my code is working fine when I use action method in regular controller but when url is to webapi it can not get the data

Comment: Use firebug to test post data.

Comment: the data is ok on client side but the problem is webapi uses different model binding than mvc

Comment: decorating your action parameter with the [FromUri] attribute. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628576/passing-an-json-array-to-mvc-web-api-via-get) post may help you.

Answer (score 2):

At last, based on @Shashank Answer it worked and the code modified as :

```
var deletedIds = new Array();

deletedIds.push(modelId);

var postData = { "DeletedIds": deletedIds };
$.ajax({
    type: "Delete",
    traditional: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    url: "/api/Management/Models",
    data: postData,
    success: ModelDeleted,
    error: ModelNotDeleted
});
```

and the apiController :

```
[HttpDelete]
        public bool DeleteModels(DeleteViewModel dvm)
        {
            return modelsRepository.DeleteModels(dvm.DeletedIds);
        }
```

and for the DeleteViewModel :

```
public class DeleteViewModel
    {
        public int[] DeletedIds { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the stringify bit is messing up your object - have you tried assigning it to a variable to see if it's the expected formatting?

You're stringifying the whole thing at the moment:

`{ "deletedIds": deletedIds }`

while what you probably want to send as post body is this:

`{ "deletedIds": JSON.stringify(deletedIds) }`

Comment: And either way, if your controller method expects integers, why stringify them in JS?

Comment: stringify was just a try I made up a test action method in a regular controller and it works mvc modelbinder works but webapi not !!

Comment: @MuhammadAlaa - post the exact JSON you're sending with the request. Is the controller method hit at all? Are you getting an empty array?

Comment: I tried to send static data just for test I get an empty array in the apicontroller method

Comment: @Muhammad Alaa - post here the JSON you are sending, static or not, otherwise I can't help you