# Only first POST method of controller is called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a couple of post methods in my controller. Whenever I post data to this controller, only the first POST method is called. My requirement is to call the second method as the parameters are going to be different for both the methods. Here is the route config:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "AddUser",
routeTemplate: "api/users/adduser",
defaults: new { controller = "users" }
);
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "ChangeUser",
routeTemplate: "api/users/changeuser",
defaults: new { controller = "users" }
);
```

This is my controller's code:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[ActionName("adduser")]
public string PostDetails(JObject userData)//Always this method is called.
{
//My code here
}

[AllowAnonymous]
[ActionName("changeuser")]
public string ChangeUser(int userId)
{
//My code here
}
```

This is called from the view:

```
Ext.Ajax.request( { url: 'localhost/myapp/api/users/changeuser'
                  , mode: 'POST'
                  , params: { userID: 1 }
                  }
                );
```

Comment: Can you show the calling code (form in view)?

Comment: I am using ExtJS in client side. This is how I call these methods: Ext.Ajax.request({
url: 'localhost/myapp/users/changeuser',
mode: 'POST',
params: {
userID: 1
}});

Comment: Please add your code into the question, not in comments.

Comment: Any errors in your browser console?

Comment: No. I can debug the code. It returns the result from the fist post method"add user".

Comment: Try decorating the second method with `HttpPost` attribute.

Comment: No idea why it is overwriting your action, however, you have not defined `userID = UrlParameter.Optional` in your defaults for the `change user` route.  Perhaps this has something to do with it.

Comment: Could you first map the second route and then see if it happens.

Answer (score 1):

Adding constrains in the route config will solve your problem. Try below config..

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "AddUser",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
defaults: new { },
constraints: new { controller = "users", action = "adduser" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "ChangeUser",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
defaults: new { },
constraints: new { controller = "users", action = "changeuser" }
);
```

The C# part:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[ActionName("adduser")]
[AcceptVerbs("Post")]
public string PostDetails(JObject userData)//Always this method is called.
{
//My code here
}

[AllowAnonymous]
[ActionName("changeuser")]
[AcceptVerbs("Post")]
public string ChangeUser(int userId)
{
//My code here
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. Still "AddUser" method is getting called.

Comment: I updated the C# code part also. The route template string must be exactly "api/{controller}/{action}". Don't use the controller name or action name in the route template. The constraints will check for the controller and action from the given url..

Comment: I changed it as per the code provided but now if I call the controller as "localhost/myapp/api/users", it goes to the same method(the first post method). If I call the controller as "localhost/myapp/api/users/changeuser", it gives 404 error.

Comment: I think the problem is your changeuser method. it accepts integer as a parameter. you have to modified it to the value type. create one class which contains one integer property, and use that class as a parameter. refrer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374954/passing-array-of-integers-to-webapi-method

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Name")]
```

instead of:

```
[ActionName("Name")]
```

I'm not an expert but it might work this way.

Comment: Can you post the .net part?

Comment: I have already posted that in my question(Controller methods).