# passing Json Array to MVC Controller Action returning Null

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, getjson

passing Json Array to MVC Controller Action returning Null  .

```
**controler*** 
public class TestData
{
    public string name1  { get; set; }
    public string value1 { get; set; }   
}

public JsonResult MyMethod(List<TestData> testVal)
    {
 //testval object having name1 and value1 null values
  }
```

view page

```
      $.getJSON("/viewFolderName/MyMethod",
         {
             testVal: [{ name1: "veea", value1: "0" }]

         },
         function (data) {
         //result
         });
```

passing Json Array to MVC Controller Action returning Null

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14628736/1384539

Comment: above link solution is not clear

Comment: don't use $.getJSON, but $.ajax

Answer (score 0):

No, don't try to be sending JSON in a GET request. Use JSON with other verbs which have body, such as POST and PUT.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/viewFolderName/MyMethod',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { testVal: [{ name1: "veea", value1: "0" }] },
    traditional: true,
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
});
```